# $f(x)=x+2+2\ln x.$. Find the number of solutions of $f.$ Help?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I have found that f is increasing, its domain is Df=(0,+oo) and f((0,+oo)) = R
How do i find the number of solutions of f and how am i explaining it? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "solution" of f? Do you mean "zero"?

Comment: "Solutions"?? What solutions? There is no equation here...

Comment: Domain of the function is $x\in (0, +\infty)$?

Comment: @MarkPineau  Roots is usually reserved for the points at which *polynomial* functions vanish. But I guess we can use that name in case of other kind of functions. Why, where or from what do you see that it's "obvious" what the OP means?? This is very hard for me to understand. Even more, from where do you deduce that if the OP did *not* mean what you are **guessing** he meant, then he *must have meant* something else, like the function's domain? The answer given has already been accepted, which means the OP was simply lousy to write correctly his question, as he *at least* knows some calculus

Comment: I haven't made any mistakes in the question, the question says find the solutions of f. Just nothing more.
Thanks to salahamam who made it clear that when it asks you find the solutions of f , means find the solutions of f(x)=0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For $x>0$,

$$f'(x)=1+\frac 2x=\frac {x+2}{x} >0$$

$$\implies $$ $f $ is strictly increasing from $(0,+\infty) $ to $\mathbb R $

$f $ is continuous at $(0,+\infty) $
thus it is bijective.

the equation $f (x)=0$ has only one root.

Comment: Why answer when the asker hasn't even specified what is meant by the number of solutions to $f(x)=x+2+2\ln x.$.?  Your "answer" assumes too much.  If you want so badly to answer, when you don't even know what the question is, then you've got to use, or practice, some personal restraint.

Comment: He means the roots of $f (x)=0$.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you see a comment from the asker that says as much? Cuz...it isn't there as of the time of post of this comment!

Comment: @MarkPineau it is bijective and its range is $(-\infty,+\infty) $.

Comment: I think it is slightly annoying seeing people *guessing* what the question is **and then** answering their own guessing. If the OP doesn't even bother to clear out the doubts his poorly worded question arises, I think nobody should try to guess what his intention was and then answer it. I though won't answer, but I understand the downvoter. And the above is **not** a right answer...at least, not one to what the OP meant, which we *still don't know what it is* .

Comment: good night everybody . it is too late here.

Comment: @DonAntonio I could easily solve this if i knew what find the solutions of f means. Thanks to Salahamam_ Fatima it is now clear that it means find the solutions of f(x)=0. So f  can cross the x axis (y=0) only once => there is only one solution and that's the part i was missing. So this question was stated that way to confuse whoever tried to solve it and it achieved as it confused me, you and others as i see. Calm down now.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΚορναράκης If you didn't understand what "solutions of $f$" meant, perhaps you should ask this as your question instead, rather than hoping someone would assume what you meant to ask. Just some advice for next time.

Comment: @DonAntonio Kudos to you... annoying indeed!

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΚορναράκης I don't think you understood what I was trying to say. Try to identify what specifically is _your_ problem with the question, and what _you_ don't understand, and phrase the question to reflect this. It will be more beneficial to you this way - don't simply quote the problem which is given in the textbook/paper. I am not trying to make it hard, I am just giving you advice on wording your questions more clearly in future.

Comment: @John Doe,Thanks for ur advice. If someone know mathematics, it must be impossible to not know the different ways a question can be worded. In my case "number of solutions of f" and "number of solutions of f(x)=0" is the same question but worded in a bit different way. How is it possible to be more clear? I say what i know, and finally i'm trying to say that you can't find mistake or vagueness in my question if you know mathematics. The guy above solved it correctly in a minute, because he knew 1000% what the question cleary asked and i am also 10000% sure the solution is correct.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΚορναράκης of course, if this is how you understand it, then I suppose your question makes complete sense. The problem which arose here (leading to the question being put on hold) was that normally when you say solutions, you need to have an equation to solve, so strictly speaking, you should have written "find the solutions to the equation $f(x)=0$, since this is an equation, $f(x)$ by itself is just an expression. Anyway, it was just a misunderstanding here, I don't think there's much left to discuss. (I also do agree with the solution)